# custom nearbuy places using google places api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I got this from internet.

```
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    type: ['store']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

How can I search for custom locations like CVS pharmacies instead stores, withing 5 miles of radius? Also can you provide reference about full set of properties of  nearby Search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearbySearch() method accesses to Google server. So you can not add your data.

Alternative way is fusion tables.
If you have your own data, import it to Google Fusion Table, and implement your data with FusionTablesLayer.
You can search your data with SQL.
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/nn_example